# Image inside div, displayd as is, without margin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, background-image

I have a lengthy, long image (1280 x 498) that I will put inside a div as background.

My div is a Bootstrap `jumbotron` class div

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
```

Setting the image as `background-image` makes it responsive and is behind a form, just like I want it.

Problem : 
The height of the image is less than 498, so it appears cropped. I have to set extra padding and margin, but this adds unnecessary scroll to the page. 
I add `padding-bottom: 4%;` that will add extra scrolling at some screen size.

Also, if the page is really small, the image is responsive, but its height is less than the form, making the whole design ugly. I guess I could a media query that will increase margin and padding in small screens, but this makes the image repeat in y axis.

Any ideas?

Thanks

---

My code now

```
<div id="scott" class="jumbotron text-center">


#scott{
    background-image: url("../images/scott.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 4%;

}


@media (max-width: 400px) {
      #scott {
        padding-bottom: 8%;
        margin-bottom: 8%;
      }      
}
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    #scott{
    background-image: url("../images/scott.jpg");
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a basic manipulation of your background like you want is no need for media. Use media for scaling your form box to be mobile compliant.

You can try the following styling to achive what you are looking for:

```
#scott {
    background: no-repeat url("background.jpg") center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;        
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: @Turnip As you can see my post is using background not background-image and also is using center and no-repreat for a better positioning of the background. I do apologise if you still consider this as being a duplicate but I thought is a better and cleaner way of doing this.